# SVN won't ignore directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN client and I want to ignore `venv/` of a Python project. I am setting the `svn:ignore` property in of the root directory to `venv/` - no result. I am setting `svn:ignore` in root directory to `venv/` and apply it recursively to all folders (not necessary, just because I can and for doublechecking) - no result. I add the folder to VCS and set the `snv:ignore` property in `venv` to `*` - all files are ignored.

Why is it not possible to ignore the whole directory in SVN? Is it just not possible? What else can I try?

Comment: Is it already under version control? Because `svn:ignore` only applies to unversioned items, it will neither remove files from repository nor discard future changes.

Comment: Yes, I did everything right without a doubt. In frustration I set `svn:ignore` of root directory to `venv` without the slash and it worked as excepted. I don't know if this is the used SVN version, a Windows glitch or whatever, but it is against every tutorial, stackversion thread or chatGPT answer I found online.

Comment: Yes, of course, I missed the obvious part. The property expects a file name, not a path.

Comment: But why are so many instructions wrong - not a real question, I am just frustrated :)

Comment: Well, I guess that if you use TortoiseSVN in the first place, you don't typically *type* file names. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `svn:ignore` in root directory to `venv` without slash did the trick, despite every source I checked said different.